# Require previous password as validation to save settings in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want people to have to enter their password when they want to change it.

This is how I do:

```
if(bcrypt($request->password === Auth::user()->password)
{
//Do something
}
```

I want to do it correctly and Laravel style. I would be surprised if Laravel did not already have a proper function for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I were in your case I'd try something like

```
 if (Auth::attempt(['email' => Auth::user()->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {
        // Authentication passed...
        //Do something

    }
```

this will keep things clean and using the Auth which will for example reject the attempt if the user mail isn't confirmed.

look at [this part in Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#authenticating-users)
Don't forget to include
`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;`